# Error : "no such file or directory" when adding GitLab private repo in NPM package.json

Tags: git, npm, gitlab, npm-install, package.json

I am trying to add a GitLab private repository in another project `package.json`

```
  "dependencies": {
    "project": "git+https://myusername:gitlabTokenGenerated@gitlab.com/groupName/project.git",
    "mysql2": "^3.6.2"
  }
```

I am getting this error :

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-cloneAfWhq/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-cloneAfWhq/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

It seems that some cache files are missing, but when I delete this line and run the npm install, everything is OK. As i can understand, it means that the added `"git+https://myusername:gitlabTokenGenerated@gitlab.com/groupName/project.git"` is the problem.

There is a package-lock.json inside the repository, which does not include this private dependency, but I still have the problem when I delete it and only keep the package.json.

Maybe some cache issue, making the package.json file ran from elsewhere on the disk instead of using the one in repository, and raising an error when detecting that the cache does not match the actual package.json from repository ? This is the only guess i can make from my point of view.

Any idea if I could be right or what is the problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

SSH method:

- `git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/groupName/project#{branch|tag}`
- `git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/groupName/project#{branch|tag}`

Using HTTPS:

- `git+https://myusername:gitlabTokenGenerated@gitlab.com/groupName/project#{branch|tag}`